# Is there a ruby library to generate Bootstrap components?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

It seems like there ought to be a library out there that will make it easier to generate the view markup for various bootstrap components.  Perhaps this exists, but the search results I'm getting are all related to the bootstrap-css gem (or similar).

For clarity, what I'm imagining is a library that would allow me to do something like this with BS alerts, cards, modals, etc:

```
  .container
    .row
      - @gardens.each do |garden|
        -@bootstrap.panel(:title => garden.title, :thumbnail => "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/food/", :body => garden.description)
```

instead of this:

```
  .container
    .row
      - @gardens.each do |garden|
        .col-md-3
          .panel.panel-default
            .panel-heading
              .panel-title= garden.title
            .panel-body= garden.description
              .thumbnail= image_tag("http://lorempixel.com/g/400/300/food")
```

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Fullscreen/bh](https://github.com/Fullscreen/bh) project which seems to provide what you're looking for, but keep in mind that the `Card` component is currently in `alpha` so I'm not sure if there's a production-ready lib that provides a helper for this one.

Comment: Actually, I'm using BS3 and just realized that cards are only available in 4, so that's not a problem for me.  Perfect answer - thanks!